# Waiting for a table to load completely using selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want to scrape some data from a page which is in a table. So I am only bothered about the data in the table. Earlier I was using Mechanize, but I found sometimes some of the data are missing, especially in the bottom of the table. Googling, I found out that it may be due to mechanize not handling Jquery/Ajax.

So I switched to Selenium today. How do I wait for one and only one table to load completely and then extract all links from that table using selenium and python? If I wait for complete page to load, it is taking some time. I want to ensure that only data in the table is loaded. My current code:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
for page in range(1, 2):
    driver.get("http://somesite.com/page/"+str(page))
    table = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.datatable')
    links = table.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
    for link in links:
        print link.text
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`WebDriverWait`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#explicit-waits) to wait until the table is located:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

...
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
table = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.datatable'))
```

This would be an *explicit wait*.

---

Alternatively, you can make the driver [*wait implicitly*](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#implicit-waits):

> An implicit wait is to tell WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain
>   amount of time when trying to find an element or elements if they are
>   not immediately available. The default setting is 0. Once set, the
>   implicit wait is set for the life of the WebDriver object instance.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # wait up to 10 seconds while trying to locate elements
for page in range(1, 2):
    driver.get("http://somesite.com/page/"+str(page))
    table = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.datatable')
    links = table.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
    for link in links:
        print link.text
```

Comment: Thanks :) Does the explicit wait of presence_of_element_located ensure that table is fully loaded and not just partially ? Sorry, if this is too silly a question, I have no idea about it. Also I wanted to have something, so that I do not wait for other elements in the page and only the table. Once the table has loaded, I should go ahead, instead of waiting for other elements

Comment: @user3215014 if `precense_of_element_located` doesn't make a difference here, set up and implicit wait - should help.

Comment: is `datatable` the type of the div or the class name?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use Selenium's expected conditions (http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp), e.g.

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
>>> from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
>>> from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
>>> 
>>> ff = webdriver.Firefox()
>>> ff.get("http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html")
>>> try:
...     element = WebDriverWait(ff, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "example")))
...     print element.text
... finally:
...     ff.quit()
... 

Engine Browser Platform Version Grade
Gecko Firefox 1.0 Win 98+ / OSX.2+ 1.7 A
Gecko Firefox 1.5 Win 98+ / OSX.2+ 1.8 A
Gecko Firefox 2.0 Win 98+ / OSX.2+ 1.8 A
Gecko Firefox 3.0 Win 2k+ / OSX.3+ 1.9 A
Gecko Camino 1.0 OSX.2+ 1.8 A
Gecko Camino 1.5 OSX.3+ 1.8 A
Gecko Netscape 7.2 Win 95+ / Mac OS 8.6-9.2 1.7 A
Gecko Netscape Browser 8 Win 98SE+ 1.7 A
Gecko Netscape Navigator 9 Win 98+ / OSX.2+ 1.8 A
Gecko Mozilla 1.0 Win 95+ / OSX.1+ 1 A
```