# Selenium PhantomJS webdriver failing to grab ajax content

Tags: python, ajax, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am trying to scrape a page that loads most of its content via ajax.

I am trying to grab all `li` nodes with a `data-section` attribute from [this webpage](http://www.thehindu.com/archive/web/2014/11/14), for example. The response html has six required nodes that I need, but the majority of the rest are loaded via an ajax request which returns html containing the remaining `li` nodes.

So I switched from using requests to using selenium with PhantomJS driver a its supposed to be xhr friendly but I am not getting the extra ajax loaded content.

Runnable:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from lxml import html

br = webdriver.PhantomJS()
br.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(br.page_source)
print tree.xpath('//li[@data-section]/a/text()')
```

In brief, above code cannot get html injected into the webpage via xhr. How can I make it do so? If not, what are my other headless options.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Waiting for a table to load completely using selenium with python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25221580/waiting-for-a-table-to-load-completely-using-selenium-with-python)

Comment: @ArtjomB. thanks, although in that question, there is a unique table that the expected condition can check for, here there seems to be an arbitrary number of identical `li` elements being loaded. Would you have any hints how to check for that? EC solution sounds better than an implicit wait which will slow down the crawl

Comment: Since the number of elements is previously not known, you should try it with an [implicit wait](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits). I don't know your site, if there is nothing that can be used as a condition then you need to use an implicit wait.

Comment: @ArtjomB. just edited that in my earlier comment. I am going to crawl tens of thousands of pages and implicit wait doesn't sound very attractive. The network is erratic so I'll have to set a crippling value to implicit wait to account for slow periods, which will also drag down the crawl during good network as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The linked page prominently displays a loading spinner (`.archive_loading_bar`) which vanishes as soon as the data is loaded. You can use an [explicit wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#explicit-waits) with the expected condition of `invisibility_of_element_located`.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from lxml import html

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.archive_loading_bar')))
tree = html.fromstring(driver.page_source)
```

This is adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25222709) and waits up to 10 seconds or until the data is loaded.

Comment: Thanks a lot. For any future viewers- the `driver` on line 6 should be replaced by `br` and the arguments inside `invisibility_of_element_located` should be a tuple (only accepts one argument) so an extra pair of brackets must be added.