# Webdriver in Python How to wait for the HTML table to load

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium Webdriver with Python. I am having trouble in how to wait for the table to complete loading.

The webpage displays a table of columns (Name, Variable, Feed etc). Each row has data for each column. E.g. Lucy, Name, datafeed. I am checking if the data is correct in each row in the if statement. I need to wait for all of the rows in the table to be loaded to avoid Element is no longer valid.

What is the best way to wait for the whole table to be loaded?
I have tried using WebdriverWait.  I think my syntax is in the wrong place.

My code is:

```
def is_mappings_details_saved(self, name, dataset, feed, variable):
            try:
                #self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
                wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20)
                table_id = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'data_configuration_mappings_ct_fields_body')))
                rows = table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
                for row in rows:
                    time.sleep(1)
                    # Get the columns
                    col_name = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[1]  # This is the Name column
                    col_variable = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[2]  # This is the Variable column
                    col_feed = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[3]  # This is the Feed column
                    col_data_category = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[4]  # This is the Data Category column
                    col_dataset = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[6]  # This is the Dataset column
                    col_datamap = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[7]  # This is the Datamap column
                    if (col_name.text == name) and (col_variable.text == variable) and (col_feed.text == feed) and (col_data_category.text == "Main") and (col_dataset.text == dataset) and (col_datamap.text == self.datamap_name):
                        return True
                return False
            except NoSuchElementException, e:
                return False
```

The error is:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Element is no longer valid
```

The line highlighted at the error is:

```
rows = table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
```

I wait for the table to load and then find the rows.  Do i not need to find the rows if i have the whole table?

The HTML snippet is:

```
<table id="data_configuration_mappings_ct_fields_body" cellspacing="0" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">
<colgroup>
<tbody>
    <tr class="GOFU2OVFG GOFU2OVMG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="0">
    <td class="GOFU2OVEG GOFU2OVGG GOFU2OVHG GOFU2OVNG">
    <td class="GOFU2OVEG GOFU2OVGG GOFU2OVNG">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-418" style="outline-style:none;">
            <span class="linkhover" title="Name" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;color:#00A;cursor:pointer;">Name</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GOFU2OVEG GOFU2OVGG GOFU2OVNG">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-419" style="outline-style:none;">
            <span class="" title="Name" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">Name</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GOFU2OVEG GOFU2OVGG GOFU2OVNG">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-420" style="outline-style:none;">
            <span class="" title="crm" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">crm</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GOFU2OVEG GOFU2OVGG GOFU2OVNG">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-421" style="outline-style:none;">
            <span class="" title="Main" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">Main</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GOFU2OVEG GOFU2OVGG GOFU2OVNG">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-422" style="outline-style:none;">
            <span class="" title="TITLE + FNAME + SNAME" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">TITLE + FNAME + SNAME</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GOFU2OVEG GOFU2OVGG GOFU2OVNG">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-423" style="outline-style:none;">
            <span class="" title="CRM" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">CRM</span>
        </div>
    </td>
        <td class="GOFU2OVEG GOFU2OVGG GOFU2OVNG">
        <td class="GOFU2OVEG GOFU2OVGG GOFU2OVBH GOFU2OVNG">
    </tr>
    <tr class="GOFU2OVEH" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="1">
        <td class="GOFU2OVEG GOFU2OVFH GOFU2OVHG">
            <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-417" style="outline-style:none;">
                <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
            </div>
        </td>
    <td class="GOFU2OVEG GOFU2OVFH">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-418" style="outline-style:none;">
            <span class="linkhover" title="DOB" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;color:#00A;cursor:pointer;">DOB</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GOFU2OVEG GOFU2OVFH">
    <td class="GOFU2OVEG GOFU2OVFH">
    ... etc     
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks, Riaz

Comment: is your table appear after any event? or is it load in man page? is there any id, name or unique identifier of your table?

Comment: It is loaded in the main page.  Table ID is data_configuration_mappings_ct_fields_body

Comment: Do you know how many rows would there be loaded into the table?..

Comment: 4 rows at the moment.  The client could enter more data later so it could end up 10 rows or so

Comment: In other words, I'm trying to define smth we can rely on. How you, as a human, define that the table is loaded - is there any indication?..

Comment: actually, selenium doesn't start progress before entire page is loaded. not need to wait.

Comment: alecxe - The user clicks add button, fills in the form fields. Clicks Save.  The table is then shown. You can see the mouse cursor animate while table loads.

Comment: so, your table firstly not displayed, isn't it? after click on add and save button it become visible? or, it is currently visible but  new added lines appeared later?

Comment: After you click save the table appears.

Comment: so, why wait for visibility of table by id is not a solution?

Comment: I am going to try table_id = self.find_element('By.ID, 'data_configuration_mappings_ct_fields_body')
            rows = table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")

Comment: I get Element is no longer valid.  I need to use WebdriverWait somehow.

Comment: I am going to try rows = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr"))

Comment: I now get TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Is there any progress bar while saving?

Comment: Yes there is a progress bar.

Comment: I remember now why i was trying to use WebdriverWait.  Before it was not loading all of the columns.  There were about 7 columns, the for loop was only going up to 6 columns.  The dev advised to wait for all the columns to be loaded

Comment: I am going to try this code before i find the table WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(lambda d: d.execute_script('return document.readyState'))

Comment: I got Timeout Exception using document.readState

Comment: I am going to now try to put a wait to wait for columns to be loaded and a wait for all rows to be loaded  WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'td')))
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'tr')))

Comment: Wait for all cols and rows to be loaded gives me Element is no longer valid.

Comment: What would be the best approach to wait for the table of rows and cols to be loaded?

Comment: @alecxe - you had answered a smilar problem with wait for table to load and it has green tick.  I will try this.  Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25221580/waiting-for-a-table-to-load-completely-using-selenium-with-python

Comment: I have just managed to solve it now.  It works now finally.  After having tried all day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve it.  Just wait for the table container to load.  Not wait for rows and columns.
I also put self.driver.implicitly_wait(20) in the base class

```
class BasePage(object):

def __init__(self, driver):
    self.driver = driver
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(20)

class MappingsPage(BasePage):
    def is_mappings_details_saved(self, name, dataset, feed, variable):       
         table_id = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'data_configuration_mappings_ct_fields_body')))
         rows = table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
         for row in rows:  
         # Get the columns
         col_name = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[1]  
        col_variable = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[2]  
    etc...
```

Comment: Glad to see you've solved it.  Consider marking your answer as accepted when the system would allow you to do that.

Comment: can u share about `WebDriverWait` what the package need i import ?

Comment: from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait